# conda not updating pandas

Tags: pandas, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update pandas to the latest version (0.23.3) this way:

```
conda update pandas
```

I get this message:

```
All requested packages already installed.
```

But when I check (after restarting Python) using `pd.__version__` I'm still at 0.23.1

Am I doing something wrong? Or is Anaconda not current?

Comment: Yes, same issue yesterday, last version is `0.23.1` in [conda packages](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas), so need wait for update.

Answer (score 1):

The conda package was not updated yet. Try to upgrading with pip.

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: Is it not a concern that upgrading the anaconda distribution with pip will break things?

Comment: I never got problems with that. Normally, some dependencies need to be installed in your environment, like gcc and other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The latest anaconda releases for pandas are listed below. So if you are using Win 32/64, you will only see v0.23.1 until they update the repo.

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas

```
linux-ppc64le  v0.23.2
osx-32  v0.16.2
linux-64  v0.23.2
win-32  v0.23.1
osx-64  v0.23.2
linux-32  v0.23.2
win-64  v0.23.1
```